# Central Difference Approximation with sin(y^2)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

Consider the Boundry Value ODE:

$(d^2\ T)/(dy^2\ )=\sin(y^2\ )$

Derive the equation for approximating the interior points using the central difference method.

I'm kinda stuck on this one. I was able to derive the equation down to this form:

$T_{i-1}[\frac{1}{∆y^2}]+T_i [\frac{-2}{∆y^2}]+T_{i+1} [\frac{1}{∆y^2} ]=sin(y_i)^2$

With the forcing function on the right, but I feel like I am missing something or doing something wrong. i.e. Am i supposed to do something with the sin at the end?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please decide what the form of your non-linearity is, $\sin (y^2)$ or $\sin^2y=\sin(y)^2$? /// The grouping in LaTeX/mathjax is achieved with curly braces, `T_{i+1}` gives $T_{i+1}$. Also explore the use of `\frac{a}{b}`, $\frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you get the linear equations
$$
\dfrac{T_{i-1}-2T_i + T_{i+1}}{\Delta y^2} = \sin (y_i^2), \quad i=1, \cdots, n
$$

Now you just need to solve this (tridiagonal) linear system, getting the values of $T_0$ and $T_{n+1}$ from the boundary conditions. The $\sin (y_i^2)$ terms are know and correspond to the rhs of the linear system.